# как выделить блок памяти в c++

Tags: c++, winapi

вот так выглядит все задание полностью - Основной поток создает два других потока приостановленными и после их создания запускает первый. Первый из них выделяет блок памяти размеров 200Кб, заполняет его случайными числами и запускает второй потом, который записывает сгенерированные случайные числа в файл, освобождает выделенную память и завершается

вот так у меня есть на данный момент

```
#include "pch.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> 
#include "conio.h" 
#include <vector> 
//#include "stdafx.h" 


using namespace std; 
const int Length =200 * 1024; 
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[Length]; 

int num; 


DWORD WINAPI thread2(LPVOID); 
DWORD WINAPI thread3(LPVOID); 

int main() 
{ 
// create threats 
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread2, NULL, 0, NULL); 
HANDLE thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread3, NULL, 0, NULL); 

// stop threads 
SuspendThread(thread); 
SuspendThread(thread1); 


ResumeThread(thread); 
_getch(); 
return 0; 
} 

DWORD WINAPI thread2(LPVOID t) 
{ 

for (int i = 0; i< Length; i++) 
{ 
buffer[i] = (int)rand() % Length + 1; 
} 
for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++) 
{ 
cout « (int)buffer[i] « " "; 
cout « endl; 
} 
delete[]buffer; 


//cout « "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"; 
return 0; 
} 
DWORD WINAPI thread3(LPVOID n ) 
{ 

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Что значит "заполнял случайными числами"? Числами какого размера? Один байт? Больше? Откуда и зачем у вас вдруг взялся некий `int *Arr` и почему именно `int`?

Comment: Если я правильно понял задание, то нужно чтобы эти 200кбайт заполнялись случайными целыми числами
в любом случае в задании написано " Первый из них(поток) выделяет блок памяти размером 200Кб, заполняет его случайными числами и запускает второй поток"

Comment: Вот у вас выделен блок памяти в первой же строке.

Comment: Вместо *buffer нужно всёравно 200*1024. Вместо Arr  нужно buffer.Вторая строчка не нужна. После правок - уйдет ещё лишний кусок кода. Всё.

Comment: @Антон Если вам нужен именно блок `int`ов, то зачем вы выделяли какой- то блок байтов?

Comment: А выводить на экран  `cout << (int)(buff[i]) << " ";`

Comment: не могли бы вы прислать листинг, немного не вьезжаю

Comment: Это не программа, а какая-то бессмыслица. На SO ведь не разрешают просто школьные задания, требуют хоть что-то свое написать. Так что писалось явно не задумываясь, лишь бы было похоже на настоящую программу. Левая кавычка вместо << смотрится особенно забавно.

Comment: Можно узнать почему это бессмыслица?
и я дико извиняюсь, но это не кавычка, а именно <<
видимо ваше зрение вас уже подводит

Comment: Это бессмыслица потому что эта программа не скомпилируется даже после того как вы самые дикие ошибки убрали. Еще производит впечатление ручная синхронизация потоков по _getch. Пользователь ждет когда потоки завершатся и нажимает Enter. Новое веяние в проектировании многопоточных приложений. А насчет подводит зрение - вот этот символ "«" это никак не две угловые скобки "<<".

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо вначале открыть книжку и стать чуточку сильнее.

Вначале я посмотрел на это

```
byte *buffer = new byte [200*1024];
```

нормально выделили памяти, 200 килобайт (правда производители дисков скажут, что здесь 204.8 килобайта). Правда тип [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) доступен только с 17 плюсов, а значит не каждый школьный компилятор его возьмет. Но может тут просто обычный `#define byte char`

Но потом я увидел это

```
int *Arr = new int[*buffer];
```

buffer - это указатель на массив, а `*buffer` это `*(buffer+0)`, то есть `buffer[0]`. То есть, выделяем ещё один массив int, размер которого записан в первом элементе массива. Очень интересно. Дело в том, что сам то buffer[0] ещё не инициализированный, поэтому, код может выделить любое кол-во байт (в определенном диапазоне конечно).

Смотрим дальше

```
for(int i=-; i< *buffer; i++)
```

явно переписывалось с какого ксерокса. Выражение `int i=-;` не валидное. И скорее всего имелось ввиду `int i=0;`.

Но  на этом это выражение не завершилось. Смотрим в вторую половину `i< *buffer` - пока i меньше значения нулевого элемента (неинициализированного массива). Ой. Это полный ой. Но опустив глаза на следующий цикл, мне кажется, что под `*buffer` автор имел ввиду размер массива. Тогда все стает на свои места. Даже эта строка `num = rand()% *buffer +1;` обретает смысл. Но оно и подсказывает, что byte это не std::byte. И rand по всей видимости какой то не такой

опустимся вниз. Там нас ждет `delet[]Arr;`. явно недописанная буква e. Ок.  Правда оно в цикле, но какая теперь разница:) теперь можно написать как надо.

Просто поправленная, но все равно ужасная версия

```
using namespace std;
const int LEN = 200*1024;
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [LEN];

int num;

for(int i=0; i< LEN; i++)
{
  buffer[i] = (int)rand()% LEN +1;

}
for(int i = 0; i< LEN; i++)
{
  cout << buffer[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;

}
delete[]buffer;
```

Вывод: Откройте книгу или конспект. Почитайте.

А потоки.. А нет в программе потоков. Но судя по вопросу, ищется что то вида Consumer-producer. Но это немножко более сложный код. Например, [где то так](https://github.com/sukhai/ProducerConsumer/blob/master/Win32/producer-consumer.c).

Comment: у меня при таком листинге символы постоянно печатаются, их разве не должно быть немного?
и заполняется не цифрами а буквами

Comment: поправьте вывод вот так `cout << (int)buffer[i] << " ";`

Comment: дописал в принципе как выглядит полное задание